# My Swiper.js doesn't stop on hover (only after adding speed parameter)

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, swiper.js

So I want to do this swiper.js carousel which slides linear from right to the left and after mouse hover it would stop. I used this function which works pretty fine:

```
 $(".swiper-container3").hover(function() {
        (this).swiper.autoplay.stop();
    }, function() {
        (this).swiper.autoplay.start();
 });
```

If speed parameter is not defined in my swiper initialization function, then it stops after a hover (but only if the nearest slider will be on center of carousel).
How to force swiper.js to stop with the function above but not to wait for one of the sliders to be on center?
Rest of the code

```
const enableSwiper3 = function(){
      mySwiper3 = new Swiper ('#swiper-container3', {
          loop: true,
          slidesPerView: "auto",
          spaceBetween: 10,
          centeredSlides: true,
          a11y: true,
          keyboardControl: true,
          grabCursor: true,
          freeMode: false,
          pagination: {
            el: '#swiper-pagination3',
          },
          paginationClickable: true,
          breakpoints: {
             400: {
              slidesPerView: 'auto',
              spaceBetween: 20,
              loop: true
            },
            767: {
              autoplay: {
                delay: 5000,    
                disableOnInteraction: true,
                pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
              },
              speed: 10000,
            }
          }
       });   
        mySwiper3.autoplay.start();
    }
```

I also want to lower its speed so whole slider goes linear very slow and just after hovering it it stops. Example on the site below: https://www.intercom.com/ (people are talking section).

Answer (score 0):

for smooth speed use css

```
  .swiper-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear!important; 
    -o-transition-timing-function:linear!important;
    transition-timing-function:linear!important; 
  }
```

and to stop slider immediately you can try this->

```
$(".swiper-container3").each(function(elem, target){
  var test = target.swiper;
  $(this).hover(function() {
      test.setProgress(0, 0);
  }, function() {
      test.setProgress(0, 5000);
  });
});
```